# Listview with background different than item

Tags: android, listview, background, styles, selector

I am trying to create a listview that has items with a different color background, as you can see in the lower image.

However, I accomplished this by setting the background color in the layout of the item. Now when I click on the item, there is no feedback (such as the click and ripple effect provided if there was no background).

Is there a way to set these items as a different color than the background without losing the default feedback of the on select? If not, is the common technique to create a selector?

[image: Differing background colors]

Comment: Instead of setting a png drawable as background of item layout create a xml drawable with normal and pressed state backgrounds. Than set that as bg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list_item_bg.xml in /res/drawable/ :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_normal" />
</selector>
```

now in listitem.xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg"
    ... />
```

This will allow you to have two different backgrounds for normal and pressed state.

Comment: Appreciate it. So I'm guessing the ripple effect is out of the question?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. :(